# open cv installation error in anaconda navigator

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to install opencv in anaconda navigator by using the command in anaconda command prompt

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

and got the following error

```
Fetching package metadata .........
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.continuum.io\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by ProtocolError(\'Connection aborted.\', BadStatusLine("\'\'",)))',),)
```

I installed anaconda navigator in windows 10 python version is 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a network issue but l also think the command to use is:
`conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3`